# Help with example of convergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I need to find example of a convergent and a divergent series that verify
$\frac{U_{n+1}}{U_n} = 1 - \frac{1}{n} + o(\frac{1}{n})$ where $$U_n$$ is the general term of the series

For the divergent series I found $U_n = \frac{1}{n-1}$ 
But I don't have any idea for the convergent series
I tried to simplify the expression but no result
Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to find something "smaller" (decreasing faster) than $\frac{1}{n}$ so that the series converges, but not as small so as to mess up the approximately polynomial ratio. Try $U_n=\frac{1}{(n-1)\log^2(n-1)}$.The series converges by the integral test, and:
$$ \frac{U_{n+1}}{U_n}=\frac{(n-1)\log^2(n-1)}{n\log^2 n}=(1-\frac{1}{n})(\frac{\log(n-1)}{\log n})^2
$$
with
$$\frac{\log(n-1)}{\log n}=1+\frac{-\frac{1}{n}+o(\frac{1}{n})}{\log n}=1+o(\frac{1}{n})$$ by Taylor expansion.